# In Angular, How to wait for finish async call then go to next object inside foreach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem about angular async call inside angular.forEach.

How to wait for nested async call finished, then go to next foreach object.

For below concept example.

Suppose i insert record to database  with temp code is 1200, 1201, 1202.

Now i found the problem point is first finish forEach loop by 1200, then createMember through factory, so the 3 record temp code was 1200, 1200, 1200.
how should i fix in correct loop order.

I want the sequence is

//1200
forEach 1 of $scope.xyzList -> getTempCode -> createMember -> updateTempCode,

//1201
forEach 2 of $scope.xyzList -> getTempCode -> createMember -> updateTempCode,

//1202
forEach 3 of $scope.xyzList -> getTempCode -> createMember -> updateTempCode,

Sample Concept Code as below

Suppose $scope.xyzList object list have 3 objects.

```
var data = {"code": "null"};

angular.forEach($scope.xyzList, function(v, k){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xxxx.com/getTempCode', // for example temp code: 1200
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function(obj) {
       $scope.createMember(obj, v);
    }
})

$scope.createMember = function(obj, listVal) {
    var currentCode = obj;
    var cdata = {"code": currentCode};
    var memberView = New MemberView();
    memberView.code = obj;
    memberView.name = listVal.name;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xxxx.com/checkCodeExist',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function(rs) {
       if (rs.code == null) {
          xxxxFactory.createMember($rootScope.global.systemObj, memberView)
              .then(function(result){
                  $http({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: 'http://xxxx.com/updateTempCode', // Temp code + 1
                      data: JSON.stringify(cdata),
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                  })
              })
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a forEach loop, you can use a recursive function when you need something to wait for an async process to finish. In this case, something like this:

```
  function handleListItem(list, idx) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST'
      , url: 'http://xxxx.com/getTempCode', // for example temp code: 1200
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
      , headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function (obj) {
        $scope.createMember(obj, list[idx], function () {
            var nextItem = list[++idx]
            if (nextItem) handleListItem(list, idx)
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

So now your createMember function needs to take an anonymous function as its third parameter, and call that once it finishes everything it's doing, something like this:

```
  $scope.createMember = function (obj, listVal, next) {
    // all of your code until here
    $http({
      method: 'POST'
      , url: 'http://xxxx.com/updateTempCode', // Temp code + 1
      data: JSON.stringify(cdata)
      , headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(next)
  }
```

Finally, kick everything off by calling that function with your list and the 0 index as its parameters.

```
  handleListItem($scope.xyzlist, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to persist your value in the callback. This way, you don't need to wait for the async call to finish. For example:

```
function callbackCreator(val) {
    return function(obj) {
        $scope.createMember(obj, val);
    }
}

angular.forEach($scope.xyzList, function(v, k){
    var cb = callbackCreator(v);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xxxx.com/getTempCode', // for example temp code: 1200
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use es6 `let`. Let is loop-scoped so your loop won't go into race conditions, just because the iterator is defined in every loop with its own scope. Just be careful because `for (var key in obj)` iterates over the prototype:

```
var myObj = $scope.xyzList;
for (let key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnproperty(key)) {
    let v = myObj[key];
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xxxx.com/getTempCode', // for example temp code: 1200
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function(obj) {
       $scope.createMember(obj, v);
    }
  }
}
```

Simple and clean. Hope it helps.